# simple_xml_load_string if nothing is returned

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am attempting to only run a loop if xml results actually exist. I am getting the xml results via:

```
$albums = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($api_url . '/videos.xml'));
```

What I want to be able to do is that on the next line say:

```
if($albums = hasAValue())
    // Loop
```

Any ideas? Or a way to check before I load the XML data?

Side note: This is using the Vimeo API.

Comment: print_r($albums);,You will get the result as an SimpleXMLElement

Comment: use cURL or similar to check the HTTP response headers, 200 for found, 404 for not found

Comment: Had a look at the curl errors but didn't get anywhere. Same error messages: Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in ....

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to further go down with the resultant with the namespace, reach till body give the xpath and work on.

```
$albums->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
```

To be specific, let me know the XML response you are getting i will let you the output.

UPDATED

```
$albums = simplexml_load_string("#your response#");
echo count($xml->children());
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ok, for simplicity check this. Check if children exists..if yes then you need to follow above method.... $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo count($xml->children());

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way:

```
$albums = @simplexml_load_string(curl_get($api_url . '/videos.xml'));
if ($albums) 
{
    ...
}
```

This is dirty because of [the Error Control Operator `@`](http://php.net/language.operators.errorcontrol) which is used to "deal" with the error cases (e.g. problem fetching the remote location).

The alternative is to differentiate more here:

```
$xml = curl_get($api_url . '/videos.xml');

$albums = NULL;

if ($xml) 
{
    $albums = simplexml_load_string($xml);
}

if ($albums) 
{
    ...
}
```